# Can not use groovy step definitions with cuke4duke 

Tags: cucumber, jruby, bdd

I have a working environment to run acceptance tests using cucumber/capybara, recently I have been trying to use cuke4duke from the command line through jruby (no maven, no ant) so I can define my step definitions in groovy as I am more proficient in groovy/java than ruby. Using the Calculator example from https://github.com/cucumber/cuke4duke/tree/master/examples/groovy
I get the following error:

groovy/lang/Closure (Java::JavaLang::NoClassDefFoundError)

looks like this line is failing for some reason 'this.metaClass.mixin(cuke4duke.GroovyDsl)'
and obviously I need it to make the groovy dsl available.

I've tried to run cuke4duke --jars 'folder where groovy.jar is' but I get the same result :(

Env:
jruby 1.6.3
cuke4duke 1.0.2
ubuntu 10.x
groovy 1.7.8
jdk 1.6

Any help will be much appreciated as I have not found anything relevant on google..

Cheers,

Rafael.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. The best source of information is the Cukes mailing list. This has come up before, see http://groups.google.com/group/cukes/browse_frm/thread/7a9787cd17134c4d/0e42f88225335db2. Hopefully that will get you started. Also, if all else fails, it really wouldn't take long to get proficient with Ruby :).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link, I have read it before though, in the end I 'mavenized' my project and following http://cuke4ninja.com/sec_maven.html was able to get the tests running, not sure what difference it made, apart from a different version of Jruby, unfortunately did not have time to dig deeper into the cause, cheers.